# How do I replace Hibernate with DataNucleus JPA in a JHipster project?

Tags: datanucleus, jhipster

**I'm building on top of of a JHipster template**, which uses Spring Boot, Hibernate and JPA extensively. However, I have an object structure which requires that I can traverse different levels of the object tree without returning the entire tree each time, so **I want to use the DataNucleus `fetch-group` capability** going forward.

In order to make this switch, what modifications do I need to make in my JHipster-based project?

Answer (score 0):

### Pieces of code to change:

1. pom.xml
2. main/java/resources/logback.xml
3. Reload configs
4. User persistence classes

   - cache annotations should switch from hibernate to Datanucleus

**---answer not finished----**